# Volume bounded by rotating a curve

Tags: calculus, geometry

Consider the region bounded by the curves $y=\sqrt{4−x^2}$, $y=2$, and
$x=2$. This region is rotated about the $y-$axis. What is the volume of the generated solid?

Comment: What are your starting steps? It is a circle segment rotated about y-axis

Answer (score 0):

The generated solid is a cylinder of radius 2 and height 2 with a hemisphere removed from it. The hemisphere has radius 2.

You don't need calculus to solve this problem.